Accounting for Retention Patterns in YouTube thumbnail A/B/C Testing
I am using the YouTube thumbnail A/B/C testing feature and encountering results that are implausible – I am trying to figure out why. One theory is that YouTube is not taking retention into account in its calculations, and high variance in watch time could throw off the calculations.
Context:
The videos are many hours long (2-3).
Majority of viewers (~50%) drop off within the first minute
Small percentage watch the entire video (7-10%).
Testing platform splits impressions (people who see thumbnail) equally between thumbnails.
Success metric is: (watch time for thumbnail variant)/(total watch time across all variants)
Example scenario:
If 10 people are split between 2 thumbnails (5 each), and one group happens to contain the single viewer who watches the entire video, this could heavily skew the results. My intuition is that this high variance would require more samples to get reliable results.
Questions:

Is it necessary to take account for retention patterns when calculating the best thumbnail based on watch time percentage? Or is this information unnecessary to deal with directly, as it will be reflected in watch time share percentage.

If so, how many samples would be needed for statistically significant results? What is the formula I would need to calculate this?


